# pdfkit- how to align images in one line?

Tags: node.js, backend, styling, pdfkit

I want to add an inline images to PDF file with pdfkit.
I am trying to do that using align attribute. I want to set 3 images in a row and if there is no place in the page, add another page and set the images there.
Another thing is that i see the image only one time even if I have 3 images.
Do u guys have some suggestions?
Thanks!

[image]

pdf-service.js

```
const PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');
let data = fs.readFileSync('./data.json');
data = JSON.parse(data)

async function buildPDF(dataCallback, endCallback) {
const doc = new PDFDocument({ bufferPages: true, font: 'Courier', size: 'C4' });
doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('idan.pdf'))

doc.on('data', dataCallback);
doc.on('end', endCallback);

data.forEach((memory, index) => {
const { MEM_TITLE, MEM_DATE, MEM_TEXT, MEM_IMAGE, MEM_OTHER_IMAGES, MEM_YEAR } = memory;
doc.font('Times-Roman').fontSize(20).text(MEM_TITLE + " - " + (MEM_DATE || MEM_YEAR), {
  lineGap: 15,
  underline: true
});
doc.font('Times-Roman').fontSize(14).text(MEM_TEXT, {
  lineGap: 7,
})
let numOfImages = 0
if (MEM_IMAGE) {
  numOfImages += 1
}
if (MEM_OTHER_IMAGES) {
  const otherImages = JSON.parse(MEM_OTHER_IMAGES)
  numOfImages += otherImages.length
}
for (let i = 0; i < numOfImages; i++) {
  doc.image('view.jpg', {
    fit: [200, 200], align: 'center', valign:
      'center'
  }).stroke()
}

if (index === data.length - 1) {
  doc.end()
}
doc.addPage()
})

setTimeout(() => {
fs.unlinkSync('idan.pdf')
}, 3000)
}

module.exports = { buildPDF };
```

data.json

```
[
{
    "MEM_TITLE": "Halewav licud ohepoti tenovit",
    "MEM_DATE": null,
    "MEM_TEXT": "Isihen yepatan esebigo feyewar fires dihar hina iho ren asisa oha ese etehe elo reterer\nMiteho nemoc edonih sonona esise itemeri otelos yoneses ici sohasuh nig atehose\nNesodod ocola yateh iron ere esosafe tatewut ucoroke meb inap ecerace rus amor sere yalig otetos aho\nTatosos ketet avewefa imet yin awiyiw ayarabi besa nisar sena lid afe odi\nZod atepe lov maheg tena moya neror ose fatotin ocinele ace hug ona era itata efaw abaromu\nRadosit bareye odaf iluvam asarob sidigof\nEne pus ates usa ran elon emeyen tah ibetil",
    "MEM_IMAGE": "0c8774c605185089215822955f1da862012683ce0433aecf9f9f4db4f441f3f2.jpeg",
    "MEM_YEAR": 2022,
    "MEM_OTHER_IMAGES": ""
},
{
    "MEM_TITLE": "Iteyeh sovete yale seta uyet osohef",
    "MEM_DATE": "1983-08-19",
    "MEM_TEXT": "Sip renoca itu hihan cuyut esuhibo ehosare ayopir ona\nTotesa rocepet ago oni emet heyete itebu ade otap dah enur tat tep den turaw onip ned ivu weselid\nUhirara gal ume osow ote xinu awataha etefih oliy ratipu itu nog elucaf imof migida nuteho enarot as\nOsesi ihirig yineho cefeh imicud mes\nOrirat osa heyatit nisutos rometu rotet ete vil gis letumo osi isese lemoyo aheyeh yaneni",
    "MEM_IMAGE": null,
    "MEM_YEAR": 1983,
    "MEM_OTHER_IMAGES": ""
},
{
    "MEM_TITLE": "Horoli roje iwi",
    "MEM_DATE": "1987-02-08",
    "MEM_TEXT": "Eretosa irit enatan enotesi dos wawev adasur\nElosod num idan ihanuhi eresani adit ewe yan atewip sahi gos eler olu amuder gat emirime gewe hater\nMer ena caralim iwa ogihim niraxi opey asateta\nGotiri inepem hana sidatah ome romete nuf semere ofat tona atote\nEsid uyobohi owar ori uyofa vola non eweber vives rowof eritay\nMeh roni ige niru lepehoh saniwa\nCoyar gab iranen coma tih tihe anegeno sonaro are ecide etil teye lefesu odikibi\nAhidene anarot ohol etawore dirat\nIsa ade userera sos imamam fesigo pepomem tedese nopicas ino erel ifasino oyen dute dep apanur wan",
    "MEM_IMAGE": "96d9ed75989b77ca2067192140ed18f17176d5b5d596001cea0b01b016eace75.jpeg",
    "MEM_YEAR": 1987,
    "MEM_OTHER_IMAGES": ""
},
{
    "MEM_TITLE": "Hile epa otegan tir adado reroti",
    "MEM_DATE": "2006-08-06",
    "MEM_TEXT": "Ane desu hunop asid minal zatib nato etahewi qiyofo atihis konec anirixi oled emibiwe\nEfuni yiwiwis woge howar hen lonad iharehe useli ewag coda acelo wele ineta selel net ohine\nAsehah otevem witih atenot sorilo atetih ayoceso\nNer aritine seri edehit rageho imiweli\nOmasif epica osegedi gehe ehame\nGocitig tol meyol otanod gona iwaneh daso calerol emoset fad rini etaric isener\nNorelas yaset dela etahe teta himot wade ces ore irewu usat vawulas tic roy ida\nIcahec eleba one luyen weten cer ocitu adodi",
    "MEM_IMAGE": "172a52a4fb6576796019cec1ed6a1b08a3c77fe7eba6d1d707e6efef0749a064.jpeg",
    "MEM_YEAR": 2006,
    "MEM_OTHER_IMAGES": "[\"39363b51ca65effe21758088918de8b298097c6f6e33823fcb32bf068e4918a3.jpeg\",\"34ed4360749f525afa153029f31b4038aa7861b41a15b4904e99fb3756477999.jpeg\"]"
},
{
    "MEM_TITLE": "Aveh edabosi tes tarot nuneka osi",
    "MEM_DATE": "1995-01-20",
    "MEM_TEXT": "Yamas etah lalawes edata cos isarawi ecar lar eci vicuno avor cutal taf emade het tawe woh yilel das\nSoh usemat oratige ede neto rel idiq gedim oheminu eri adip ane ota ewaf eyewido omotam haner\nDawe aruwit cet cateyo hayit afosode tasan ero busadib lul anonete meru hihahi otiniv acipu\nOsam ose asan telote tet okoleyo ado ecetu weleso diw elama\nAsa sohih bug deseros edinir ihira tih nos tocet roda simob omase efanire feb hirusol atat\nToy poter hotowi came ahesul punete rowu ime ravi osereto afor facano ebitoni\nYatitu isude rat ronot ice eba darap ceso ohedi asiruc",
    "MEM_IMAGE": null,
    "MEM_YEAR": 1995,
    "MEM_OTHER_IMAGES": ""
},
{
    "MEM_TITLE": "Idu ceyi wey eho berepec ili yeti",
    "MEM_DATE": "1994-05-21",
    "MEM_TEXT": "Hidane onaya ofirafi lehegay dife ereg\nIri avesawe sorigu agoy heseco cicodi gok eluwere refena ripamu\nAsode hitel alisi tiwo usey amar weho han telos umi\nImage edi sane tonilem tires iroruni cate ehenal cosen ohaniyi iro emu eselaha cararet etehuna\nSam rules coniso irig mid hunino nivaf tehosut etih\nNigusir osec ena ore iley pew ote ehal nir efali ditiwol sisotoc iyo egelewe aberob\nHoted ida had nihem wudas aseh set",
    "MEM_IMAGE": null,
    "MEM_YEAR": 1994,
    "MEM_OTHER_IMAGES": ""
},
{
    "MEM_TITLE": "Isom osob nobisep dah tele ritat",
    "MEM_DATE": "1992-04-07",
    "MEM_TEXT": "Igerig iyile ope ininet nevodo vusati atin hosuca otatele\nAhepeta nedega gep catagof ome menor darete ikato resapes hininot lus wiyic ehena irohi atuta\nEdosipe piton serec ihedar dehehir yonag ososa arimewa atemede udiyaya wugaf atafure\nYele nanela esedel idemol setot soled eseh neder",
    "MEM_IMAGE": "8d527e27a1737ba61ba660dfa41f65a76b9e0f8551e8c7052f93516496a5588e.jpeg",
    "MEM_YEAR": 1992,
    "MEM_OTHER_IMAGES": "[\"dddf16a88543dcc1f6eaf8efe1d7d92f102c0e1bfb587b29239c7e78c0fab0e3.jpeg\"]"
},
{
    "MEM_TITLE": "Ereveci kerele tohis ahiw dar",
    "MEM_DATE": "2000-11-11",
    "MEM_TEXT": "Funis eyase opecoye sina isetih aveh ebulihe\nTano nara lohame rohiri dihi epenah\nEdi rorugos win epeyowa renalo wed voda may wivuna ekeyis menomar nepu ewis oli heta gihesi ayuf\nIre oge lomoto tehi hec omevico dosam ofumori hete elak car iso onihe atefi\nLihenat iraneh cohiy talutin mopo iyisim mebisit irato ariro fadinat uruven heter silo egesoc\nCoyep ono apenote refet ira lipeg ecun umosec uhe puh havini yes emo cacol",
    "MEM_IMAGE": "ef369f56e9d307d92c2e36c6940352012a68dbd9c6c6d207710a1d88f6662ce3.jpeg",
    "MEM_YEAR": 2000,
    "MEM_OTHER_IMAGES": "[\"3cfa31ef318191e7fa1d6d3ffce3ebe7e3b0719873ffe01a6eeac2d7e607262d.jpeg\"]"
},
{
    "MEM_TITLE": "Vare dorano mebeda",
    "MEM_DATE": "2006-04-23",
    "MEM_TEXT": "Otesoma enec isutan erohoce suri ruhos wetanuy utaro atotos motine kihoso\nGatoh iro folet eniq olitu etoloho inu toco etase ehofato tisiho hew\nEyonepa esenom acat ece ebac taro oseli alahe ehufam amagig noson gudesel eses fahoses\nHopated iditiye gewira ete anogot otes unecis etotise",
    "MEM_IMAGE": "fedffca88b413505a2cd6d43dfcd4ddf7365c4502108487a904b32f03e156697.jpeg",
    "MEM_YEAR": 2006,
    "MEM_OTHER_IMAGES": ""
},
{
    "MEM_TITLE": "Ihitet eyin ranesa bes",
    "MEM_DATE": "2014-03-21",
    "MEM_TEXT": "Gon uno rifusu deralo casefe ilohad ada cita gonolep wer ecedide nawate yesa agu tewisor\nDasaref nere neno uta niter atete erenice otafero tehut nawonom dodoto cew areqoso onewa\nAdenone hatewep oceva kuca oroho inet odahun unapa isotoho\nGeji comer wohuves nor anegec ayu cosi rilan owe net raseci ega ovatepe rohe bogolih aloge\nUnahot dahus acuy osites eninub elem ureni dihip senos ilototo uked ebon\nFudema wedaraf iyuxele ninosa mowes olu toyem etire\nOfuto amotila olil ibetaho ati etu odo xiy tegehas osohata atadid\nOde miga xer ucenow neh welad herol ocil perer erene navo edebe nerarom ofaraci\nRepeman elanihi esaval difen enici neneloh lohey osute huco",
    "MEM_IMAGE": "5ffa1b63ee40ae2ab04ad426ab02243b1ca98bc3ec8616bad3b57df67dace04c.jpeg",
    "MEM_YEAR": 2014,
    "MEM_OTHER_IMAGES": "[\"0e9b912294fda32058f5b705e8ad2c07cf32975b6a8d70f3e329c4ee6793539e.jpeg\",\"1680a21cced11e56c25756e8297990a28a53abd0aad3fa454dfe2e83ed848d0a.jpeg\"]"
},
{
    "MEM_TITLE": "Wic ecofosi mona",
    "MEM_DATE": "1990-01-06",
    "MEM_TEXT": "Ehim ehe usuhate wot idut hacota vot etu ofadi nerereg podonol\nLosaled ate sise arodiy sifa set iwiy\nRasa sov edade sudet renic cawab sad ebetere goh seb pece nec odenita\nOrehasa eroxiha dohu onihesa osenip agemo oneko ililen lih pahom erera\nElerage eral tesit omes ape tarote ferifa ote\nIyomo ilaci eherev sisabo dikedic rayef ilad ros coh osohum peticu helu bet\nYohada ehetig onal opo enesoti ipeso ero elepefe\nUsotebo ifuheh itino edav tecu etesot tesof simuwet eyesek ete oheta edademe\nIsosoha anuyi tema sel set lopocad iretefe nasumil ekakem ole faw ohutot lade ile",
    "MEM_IMAGE": "192de05b45ac06e69c46b4208f0a5670717368ac28c0fd21228bd05bd8ed27b3.jpeg",
    "MEM_YEAR": 1990,
    "MEM_OTHER_IMAGES": ""
},
{
    "MEM_TITLE": "Ugeyeto toyug eviroh otato",
    "MEM_DATE": "1996-05-22",
    "MEM_TEXT": "Asisul isadesa agale ezares wisur hoyo ocefute lowihag dineteh ovoy dudem\nNameta ore tayo cenipit fayoxit sat iyedim bon god enat sedata erehari foci lodon rofar nif monese\nOletiv ucal ayih weyaso ovosux tawu liyo talosew asane ledoho aruretu\nNavepum retesod etanuy olese usetawo ameneri poci tugin rolanop ruhoyi oce afen pineh etod orotesa\nEtowu ifi neyihe nimiv isen eha vinodah efohima rayihom iso onep iyohi per ilitoc locey bog",
    "MEM_IMAGE": "82e80ed354465cb798751f6c2d54fcd7eeff1c27156ad678f35752dece86dee7.jpeg",
    "MEM_YEAR": 1996,
    "MEM_OTHER_IMAGES": ""
},
{
    "MEM_TITLE": "Etit ofamec ohad arane uto ona fato",
    "MEM_DATE": "2017-06-26",
    "MEM_TEXT": "Olapa ron onitum hototun hayaron itona dahare sesefor era odori yureta asotora ahat necerin\nRowipa terahe utadehi eto yenana ute sicor\nCogi mot coropan yutotep epo fepeweh canefa anohar oged isis hase iheveso ananan onuhe nit\nFudafib dacideg imovod regoba secuqi\nIge des ovof ere esivoli lebohih ehowet elif onitute\nSutino duv oleyeh yiti samu ebe otutaw rodehe nibof omoh ayidiso oroner",
    "MEM_IMAGE": "c9fc088e6d62a68eb8d46be0c9cb0f14ccdabae02def3ebc427f1e9dff694f2b.jpeg",
    "MEM_YEAR": 2017,
    "MEM_OTHER_IMAGES": "[\"2b80b9f6bf33f324c9e3254d652766708ce859ebf2bc7c00338e37eca996e13c.jpeg\",\"f60101b0344da9d5398e20358fb21fa6585f57fefb9cef1b782f84f79b6fd5a1.jpeg\"]"
},
{
    "MEM_TITLE": "Edunihi tenibe ogaba",
    "MEM_DATE": "2007-06-22",
    "MEM_TEXT": "Odom imic ihed fecum lesew isa hahaya aye inak\nZafin ape neheh tegetis oyuduc nidi yumetog nera lise edes inaroh ahi rey asi nored\nDulayi anefot etus icamog adosad owo orir ame none hatot\nGunehu ipamon yes asani agefal noneci dat",
    "MEM_IMAGE": "03ac870a3d5a434add48294f557a43f045b1ee3fd13c8c837d49946b866d634c.jpeg",
    "MEM_YEAR": 2007,
    "MEM_OTHER_IMAGES": ""
},
{
    "MEM_TITLE": "Uyace eboboya",
    "MEM_DATE": "1996-10-28",
    "MEM_TEXT": "Agiwene ebe dovih ralem eyafaho tes nalun hetat careno usen tahesag hetel\nOcen ujat nisalo ina epiba otadewo ona ugetape sohene iritino\nEdil loru nes susati seta samat texe dan asehel\nEpakeno ehoc rohetec der itoloma efaduro senehes otir sodi\nNufis dipeb eripi fawoso namubah domag etu ediha alilet binif teralif hayu",
    "MEM_IMAGE": null,
    "MEM_YEAR": 1996,
    "MEM_OTHER_IMAGES": ""
},
{
    "MEM_TITLE": "Etonif rigat ofurar ebitiri tere",
    "MEM_DATE": "2015-09-21",
    "MEM_TEXT": "Samicel tenes mefehin seser befuwus ide ikehen hecitic\nOhis esa ohuner alada akoco eneta hanic talafu udidehe tedeh\nRarano wal oyiton otur oyededo ida ifog tihata idani say tisaha olaf ena\nPiduda newedev eronin oca ofanane igo ekigop obe ril huce tow recicog nifuleh itareto inohidi\nIde ohepub cocilo ruhe dehesut tidiper aba oted ahola itinat web ceciget asot odora\nEsov erimer ufesa tecil ico age esebat ameter iledose hagaga eyecas eretor suviwo ihe esen\nAhonaf gipewe omiv yes nawa siy vicin usih reh afes edoreni canah ses olef jezega sitor igatina tah\nBuluw oqone lena oselo timut asit ite ifesuh vitocem\nOsireta nes sode hom ureten cinada enic",
    "MEM_IMAGE": "1afb57f97aa2b1302fff8f2dceeb447d22f23b10f926a258011489ba020a14ce.jpeg",
    "MEM_YEAR": 2015,
    "MEM_OTHER_IMAGES": ""
},
{
    "MEM_TITLE": "Sodat nolem ahenur heq nole gomaso",
    "MEM_DATE": "1989-05-23",
    "MEM_TEXT": "Paw niwe care ilomo noseh len ahe ehe ifi nelif\nOtoh urinos etira canig omi ces hit\nAwad eledaro ihih areh etil teri enot enelo\nPan mig lig eyana iwoyi ayina casiset isede esamar",
    "MEM_IMAGE": "cc4bdcbe411ffacc2d34163e91126ab3adfd4f36ee687ccbfa23092b9c6b54be.jpeg",
    "MEM_YEAR": 1989,
    "MEM_OTHER_IMAGES": "[\"228dbe15aea73487945bec1a58715d38d78ea8e7ea20189e52df2c1ed0a7db52.jpeg\"]"
},
{
    "MEM_TITLE": "Tewif ideyoci nisa ranal",
    "MEM_DATE": "1998-06-13",
    "MEM_TEXT": "Eso nosato ime nole coleyal tafahit sesuhe axena gewiw otoga elahus isecari apeniho\nItiriy nedoh numaw hisave sesunen deta\nAweley ayehe uve feg fecan oyas omesat kit docata alihi himuha\nInote etad nohe oleho agede utedas baset sedu tocupi",
    "MEM_IMAGE": "ffb1bf1367e4ac791ccd7df4f66ec0f7250b5abfa84b94b4468aadf02046a122.jpeg",
    "MEM_YEAR": 1998,
    "MEM_OTHER_IMAGES": ""
},
{
    "MEM_TITLE": "Girune osah teboka",
    "MEM_DATE": "1997-02-14",
    "MEM_TEXT": "Himi ihe atawiro tenot tayivi dodeyov gep aniren rosesud eheb romu ani melilo aneme\nRerode rowodi mifuw wihat otahe etuga lihodah aces osoteyu dat yaf beme elavo atumeci\nEtewuw ilarul nehad ivo ineco awe nafusib nera ilo usisi epu bumute\nEcutih emohot negere liges eyise odaropo ipada\nVerec tohec ataha venon tines ror olu ras yidadih ehib hehono teme isenit ocoti silan lese wifeh gal",
    "MEM_IMAGE": "b21dafbc76ef1e915e00a833481b7abc1ab924fbbd98a30e197364fb37dbdffc.jpeg",
    "MEM_YEAR": 1997,
    "MEM_OTHER_IMAGES": "[\"ef0c4f45594ccad897323bf06f3297f96316c262a87a774be6f5b32d9c3af652.jpeg\",\"fb9c774d2fa514bae3a0fc9b3802b857f8af64629c96d2b32084406c20967e34.jpeg\"]"
}
```

]

Answer (score 0):

When pdfkit adds an image to a document, it renders it at the next point in the text flow, however rendering an image does not advance the text flow marker. You'll have to manage the position of the image on the page manually and, if you will be adding text below the images, advance the text flow marker as well.

You may need to do some manual page management as well, as I believe auto addPage is only triggered by text, not images. You'd have to compare the image position to the length of the page and margin.

You could do it like this, as an example:

```js
// Store the current text flow marker
let imageY = doc.y;
let colIndex = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < numOfImages; i++) {
  doc.image('view.jpg', {
    fit: [200, 200], doc.x + (colIndex * 210), imageY, align: 'center', valign:
      'center'
  }).stroke()
  
  colIndex++
  // After three images, advance the marker down the page and reset the index
  if(colIndex > 2) {
    colIndex = 0;
    imageY += 210

  // If the next location is below the bottom margin, add a new page.
    if(imageY > (doc.page.height - doc.page.margins.bottom)) {
      doc.addPage();
      imageY = doc.page.margin.top
    }
  }
}
// Set the text flow marker to be below the last image
doc.y = imageY;
```